# Electron app crashes after few minutes

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm creating a clock application using Electron(1.4.13) on Mac OS X (10.11).

When I run this, its tray icon diappears after few minutes.
And the context menu will not work correctly.(app crashes by selecting an menu item)

It will work without problems until it runs for several minutes.

**main.js**

https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sample</title>
        <script>
        const remote = require('electron').remote;
        const Menu = remote.Menu;
        const MenuItem = remote.MenuItem;
        const Tray = remote.Tray;
        const NativeImage = remote.nativeImage;

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            var contextmenu = new Menu();
            contextmenu.append(
                new MenuItem({
                    label: 'Quit',
                    click: function() {
                        remote.app.quit();
                    }
                })
            );

            window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                try {
                    contextmenu.popup(ev.x, ev.y);
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
                return false;
            }, false);

            var icon = NativeImage.createFromPath(__dirname + '/icon.png');

            var tray = new Tray(icon.resize({
                width: 18,
                height: 18
            }));
            tray.setContextMenu(contextmenu);

            run();

            function run(){
                window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                    run();
                })
            }
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    test
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure what's causing this problem.
What am I doing wrong?

---

I created a repo on GitHub
https://github.com/studio-nuages/electron-example

Comment: "*crashes*"… with what error?

Comment: The error message is "Electron quit unexpectedly". Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV), Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT